# Need to direct rtsp video output to stdout

Tags: node.js, stdout, gstreamer

I need to make gstreamer take video from a rtsp uri and send the video to stdout in order to simulate similar behavior from fluent ffmpeg.

I am able to do this on a terminal ( and get raw binary data back ) but when inside of node, I get a:

> "erroneous pipeline syntax error".

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin silent=true uri=rtsp://192.168.x.x:8800/test.stm ! fdsink fd=1
```

when above command is used with a "autovideosink" I can view the video.

The reason I need to use stdout is because the existing application uses fluent-ffmpeg and it uses "pipe:1" which is basically the same thing. I want to cause the lest disruption possible to the existing application.

Inside the node application, I am invoking gst-lauch-1.0 via the "spawn" command as in:

```
var gstreamerProc = spawn(command, args, options);
```

where:

```
 command: '/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0'
 args:     ["uridecodebin","silent=true","uri=rtsp://192.168.x.x:8800/test.stm","!","queue","! fdsink fd=0"]
 options:  {"captureStdout":false,"niceness":0}"
```

And from the original fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js this comment describes the values found in "options"

```
  /*
   :
   * The 'options' argument may contain the following keys:
   * - 'niceness': specify process niceness, ignored on Windows (default: 0)
   * - `cwd`: change working directory
   * - 'captureStdout': capture stdout and pass it to 'endCB' as its 2nd argument (default: false)
   * - 'stdoutLines': override command limit (default: use command limit)
   *
   :
   */
```

As I said the above command line works on a regular terminal, no errors, no warnings yet when it is placed inside of Node.js it throws the

> "erroneous pipeline syntax"

warning.  Any help in solving this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us the code that is not working?

Comment: Thanks Florian, added invocation details.

Answer (score 1):

Not a .js expert - but I think this:

```
args:     ["uridecodebin","silent=true","uri=rtsp://192.168.x.x:8800/test.stm","!","queue","! fdsink fd=0"]
```

should be:

```
args:     ["uridecodebin","silent=true","uri=rtsp://192.168.x.x:8800/test.stm","!","queue","!","fdsink","fd=0"]
```

I think you missed some `"` and `,`.

Comment: Thanks, this is an artifact of where the argument is pushed. The default behavior of fluent ffmpeg is to push a "pipe:1" at the end of building the args array, I replaced this in the code with "! fdsink fd=1" so in effect it is the same.  I had it as one of the optional  arguments before and the result was the same. Each individual component will be concatenated to yield:

Comment: **uridecodebin silent=true uri=rtsp://192.168.1.121:8554/sensor_1001.stm ! h264parse ! queue ! fdsink fd=0**

Comment: For the last you probably will need to set the `caps` property on the decodebin. Else it will decode into raw buffers which will not fit into h264parse. However that should result in a different error other than "pipeline syntax".

Comment: Thanks Florian. Although your comment on the last command I added for clarification (and neglected to remove the h264parse from, ) it sheds some light as to what may be going wrong in my invocation. I will pursue using "decodebin" with h264parse and appropriately defining the caps in hopes that this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured out what was wrong. I set `GST_DEBUG_FILE=/tmp/gst_debug.log` and  `GST_DEBUG=*:7` to increase the logging level on both the terminal and the in the node.js app. and noticed the following:
[image]

As you can see, the gstreamer parsing dislikes the escaped spaces. I then set the `shell: true` option argument passed into *spawn* and the error disappeared.  Thank you.

Comment: A small adjustment to my original answer. I tried this without setting "sell = true" but with just eliminating the space " " between the "!" and "fdsink" and it worked fine also. So the parsing issue appears to be with the leading escaped space.